# Reusing previous host variables for groups when hostname is not static

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook where I am touching a series of firewalls, grabbing a file, naming it specifically, and uploading it to Azure blob storage.

The problem is when I switch to Azure as the destination for net_put, it promptly drops all the previous host-specific variables.

```
- name: Pull configuration backups from Palo firewalls
  hosts: groupName
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Backup configuration from Palo firewalls....
*blah
blah
blah*
    - name: Saving configuration file...
      connection: local
      check_mode: no
      ansible.builtin.copy:
        content: "{{  configuration_string['content']  }}"
        dest: '/etc/ansible/backups/{{  inventory_hostname  }}/{{  inventory_hostname  }}_{{  current_date  }}.txt'
    - name: Set fact to running session...
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        running_host: '{{  inventory_hostname  }}'
        file_string: '{{  inventory_hostname  }}_{{  current_date  }}'
- name: Copy configuration from Ansible to Azure Blob...
  gather_facts: no
  pre_tasks:
    - include_vars: /etc/ansible/sftp_secrets.yml
  hosts: AzureBlobStorage
  tasks:
    - name: Copying file to Azure blob storage via SFTP...
      ansible.netcommon.net_put:
        src: '/etc/ansible/backups/{{  running_host  }}/{{  file_string  }}.txt'
        protocol: sftp
        destination: '/{{  running_host  }}/{{  file_string  }}.txt'
```

When running the play, it failed at the first command in the new host:

```
AzureBlobStorage | FAILED! => {
    "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'running_host' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/etc/ansible/path... blah': line 44, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n  tasks:\n    - name: Copying file to Azure blob storage via SFTP...\n      ^ here\n"
}
```

I did find mention that this is apparently expected behavior as variables are specific to hosts and when you change those are not flushed, but only exist in reference to the previous host. The problem is that this playbook is intended to run against multiple endpoints and the name will not always be the same. So I cant really reference a host when I cant be certain which will be which.

My only ideas were to specify the variable from the file path, and I realized I cant without knowing the folder name... which is the hostname. Or finding a way to have a variable held globally, but I cant find any good strategies to mitigate this issue.

I was hoping someone had a good idea I didn't think of.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up going with azcopy over the Ansible native module which was a ton more successful.